# Driver.java:55: error: 'else' without 'if'

Tags: java

So basically I'm just trying to get this bit of code to work. It used to run when I had the "else" below the two "if" statements. However, when I move it above it gives me the following error:

```
Driver.java:55: error: 'else' without 'if'
```

I'd really appreciate some help solving this issue so it'll run again.

```
     {
        synchronized(someObject)
        {
           someObject.wait();
           System.out.println(ID + " has been notified.");

           Customer customer = null;

           if(Dispatcher.customerRequiresPickUp() && (customer = Dispatcher.queue.poll()) != null && (rideCount >= workFinished))         

             System.out.println("Customer has been picked up by driver #" + ID);

             try
              {
                Thread.sleep(rn.nextInt(5000) + 1000);
                System.out.println("Driver #" + ID + " has dropped off " + customer.getName() + " at " + customer.getEndLocation() + ".");
              }
              catch(InterruptedException e)
              {
              }

           else
              System.out.println("Driver #" + ID + " will continue to wait for a customer."); 

           if(rideCount >= workFinished)
             onDuty(false);
        }   
     }
```

Comment: you need brackets for the if statement

Comment: Always make use of curly braces {} to avoid confusion and error.

Comment: No enclosing brackets for the if statement. Therefore the error in this case

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Dispatcher.customerRequiresPickUp() && (customer = Dispatcher.queue.poll()) != null && (rideCount >= workFinished))
{        

         System.out.println("Customer has been picked up by driver #" + ID);

         try
          {
            Thread.sleep(rn.nextInt(5000) + 1000);
            System.out.println("Driver #" + ID + " has dropped off " + customer.getName() + " at " + customer.getEndLocation() + ".");
          }
          catch(InterruptedException e)
          {
          }
}
else
{
  System.out.println("Driver #" + ID + " will continue to wait for a customer."); 
}
```

You need curly brackets `{}` if an the body of an `if` statement is more than one line. Like so ^.